# Failure on saving article in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0

Per the title, the original text is

```
<hr id="system-readmore" />
```

After I saved, it became:

```
<hr id=\"system-readmore\" />
```

OR

```
<hr id=\"\\&quot;system-readmore\\&quot;\" />
```

Where does the problem come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of **magic quotes** is on your server. You need to turn off the **magic quotes** in your `php.ini`.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

You may refer this link: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-3-magic-quotes/ .

You may also do with `.htaccess` file add the following code to it’s own line:

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

I hope that may solve your problem.